# VS 2008 + switching between aspx/vb/js/css pages takes forever

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have been having this weird problem..

I am using Visual Studio 2008, asp.net, vb.net and switching between aspx/vb/js/css pages takes forever. Its so annoying and slows down my work.

Earlier I was using VS 2010 and never had this problem.

I am on Windows 7 (64 bit) - just in case you need this info

Anyone ever experienced this??

Please Help!
Arshya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by customizing toolbar. Removed all but Menu Bar!!

Its back to full speed!

Thanks,
Arshya